# To represent barplot in viridis color palette

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, calculated-columns, color-palette

I am trying to use viridis color plate to represent the following excel data: [image] to show Forest Percent with respect to GaPa_NaPa in barplot. I try to represent the Forest Percent using code: **ggplot(data=Rupandehi_Forest,aes(x=`Forest Percent`, fill=`Forest Percent`))+geom_bar()**. The result obtained was:- [image]. Thus, how can this be represented using viridis color and Forest Area(In Ha) be represented with respect to GaPa_NaPa.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way how we could do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  count(Forest_Percent) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Forest_Percent), y= n, fill=Forest_Percent)) +
  geom_col()+
  labs(x="Forest Percent")+
  scale_fill_viridis_d()+
  geom_text(aes(label = n), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(District = c("RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", 
"RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", 
"RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", 
"RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI", "RUPANDEHI"), GaPa_NaPa = c("Gaidahawa", 
"Kanchan", "Kotahimal", "Marchawari", "Mayadevi", "Omsatiya", 
"Rohini", "Sammarimal", "Siyari", "Sudhdhodhan", "Devdaha", "Lumbini Sanskritik", 
"Sainamaina", "Siddharthanagar", "Tillotama", "Butwal"), TotalAreaIn_ha = c(9657L, 
5835L, 5812L, 4844L, 7228L, 4844L, 6449L, 5066L, 6620L, 5743L, 
13667L, 11194L, 16082L, 3595L, 12592L, 10139L), ForestAreaIn_ha = c(726L, 
1276L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 17L, 0L, 142L, 20L, 7352L, 0L, 9115L, 
11L, 1358L, 4958L), Forest_Percent = c("7.50%", "21.90%", "0.00%", 
"0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%", "0.30%", "0.00%", "2.10%", "0.30%", 
"53.80%", "0.00%", "56.70%", "0.30%", "10.80%", "48.90%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```

Comment: Thanks But Error in UseMethod("count") : 
  no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "function" is occuring. Why?

Comment: The name of the column is different in my dataframe. maybe therefore. Check `Forest_Percent` column name in your original dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is problem with the data you worked on and the code you used. It's not happening. Could please have a look on it?

Comment: With the provided data and the code in my solution I get the provided plot.

Comment: But how can we represent bar plot in viridis pallete from data above with x axis GaPa_NaPa & y axis Forest Percent (including Title Name) ??